# Is it possible to determine individual data centers that store my data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Platform Multi-Region storage to store data for a hobby project. I wanted to have it easily backed up without much fuss, so I selected this. My data is stored in the United States and it's storage tier is managed by Autoclass.

Largely for curiosity's sake, I'm wondering if anyone knows how one can determine which data centers in Google's network are storing my data.

I'm familiar on a fundamental basis with the gsutil/command line system and how it's used, if that's how one goes about this. I'm very much new to this and I'm a hobbyist, so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Google Cloud publishes storage bucket locations: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations The `gsutil` program can display the location: `gsutil ls -Lb gs://bucketname | grep Location` Is that the information you want?

Comment: This returned that it's a multi-region bucket. I'm trying to find out which individual data centers are being used. Say `US-East-1` and `US-West-1`, I haven't found a spot in Console that says this specifically so I thought of `gsutil`.